# Maintaining backward compatibility in Service Oriented Architecture on client side

Tags: android, ios, web-services, compatibility, soa

I am in a situation where my application will get updated from the app store or play store but the Web Service APIs that the apps are using wouldn't be updated.

So, the scenario is that the client is at an updated version (e.g. 2.0) and the Web Service APIs are not (e.g. 1.0).

In this case, I need to find a pattern in which the client at the updated version can still access and use Web Service APIs of older version.

Can anyone please propose a solution for the same.

Note: My apps are built in iOS and Android respectively.

P.S.: I cannot force update the Web Service APIs.

**Example:**

My older version of the app (1.0) had a feature to enter a mandatory field which was validated in the backend web service (1.0).

Now, my latest version of the app (2.0) does not require to display the field at all (*which makes it non-mandatory*), but my app (2.0) is still accessing the web services version 1.0, hence whenever I make a request, the server would respond with an error message stating the field is required and would not allow me to save the data.

***To put it in plain words:***

***I have several deployments of server code and my client would access those servers.
The server code can be of any version (1.0,2.0,3.0) but my client would always be at the latest released version. (For e.g 3.0).
The same client still needs to access servers running at 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0***

How do I handle such scenarios?

Comment: Do you mean that your app's "Min SDK" is below what the user's device is running? And if so, then what method calls are causing you problems, (At least with Android) you should known clearly what methods should be available and which 'might' not be. They will be labelled as 'deprecated' If you avoid using deprecated methods (within the 6.0 API version) then your Android 1.0 code should work on a 6.0 device just fine.

Comment: no no, it does not have anything to do with Android Versions, by API, I mean Web services API.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to find a pattern in which the client at the updated version
>   can still access and use APIs of older version.

If you mean your app needs to use 'both' APIs, or if you mean that your app should be able to use 'either' API then you will need to have both APIs available online at the same time. To do this you have 2 main choices have unique API paths, or host them on different (sub)domains (both listed below)

---

**Different URL Paths**

The easiest answer to this is to have your web service API a /v#/ within the URL itself. This way you can easily distinguish between calls to different versions of the API.

so `www.myserver.com/webapi/v1/songs/author/` and `www.myserver.com/webapi/v2/author/songs/` for example

---

**Different (Sub)Domains**

Another approach is to have v1 web APIs run on one (sub)domain and have v2 on another...
`www.v1.myserver.com/webapi/songs/author` vs `www.v2.myserver.com/webapi/songs/author` or use `myserverv1.com` vs `myserver2.com`, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but this is not what I am facing, please check the example I have added in my question?

Answer (score 0):

If your Web API 'requires' that field be provided, then your app needs to 'provide' that field. Whether it gets it from the User or not. If the User doesn't fill in/provide that field, then you need to just enter into your API call "something valid" (This will depend on what the field is, your API, etc.) And then go from there.

Comment: Hi, that would add a lot of if else blocks in the front end code, which I am looking to avoid in this case.

Comment: I don't see why it would. Just a single if statement early in the processing to replace an empty string with a 'default' value. Then let the rest of the front-end code work the way it was previously.